# Sub-site Title as alt tag in image

Tags: 2013, spcontext, asp

I have the following code which displays a banner at the top of each page in a sub-site.  Each sub-site has a different banner.

For screen readers, I'm trying to get the alt tag to show the title of the SharePoint sub-site.  Instead of pulling the title of the sub-site ("Fluffy Bunnies"), it simply renders out the code in the alt tag `(<$SPContext.Current.Web.Title>)`

```
 <!--SPM: <asp:Image id="subhead" ImageUrl="&#60;% $SPUrl:~site/SiteAssets/Subsite_banner.png %&#62;" Tooltip="&#60;$SPContext.Current.Web.Title &#62;" alt="&#60;$SPContext.Current.Web.Title &#62;"   runat="server"/>-->
```

I have also tried using: `$SPContext.Current.Item['Title']`   to the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alt` is not a property of the ASP.NET `Image` class.  Thus, the attribute is not being executed on the server-side, the value is being passed down to the `<img>` element without being processed.  Change `alt` to `AlternateText` which is the supported `Image` class property that will execute your code on the server and pass the resolved text to the rendered `alt` attribute.

In addition, normally to bind a server-side value, you need to use `<%# %>` instead of just `<% %>` -- the `$SPUrl:` is an ASP.NET expression that is pre-processed by a SharePoint-defined appsetting.  The following should get you what you want:

```
<!--SPM: <asp:Image id="subhead" ImageUrl="&#60;% $SPUrl:~site/SiteAssets/Subsite_banner.png %&#62;" Tooltip="&#60;%# SPContext.Current.Web.Title %&#62;" AlternateText="&#60;%# SPContext.Current.Web.Title %&#62;" runat="server"/>-->
```

Depending on the type of page, to ensure that the values get bound properly, you may need to add the following to your page:

```
<script language="c#" runat="server">
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Page.DataBind();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The AlternateText worked, but when I added the <%# %>  I started getting Code Blocks Not Allowed in this file error.  @willman

Comment: You are on SP2013 on-premises, yes?

Comment: Correct SP2013 On-Premise

Comment: Do you have other pages in your environment using server-side code?  It sounds like maybe your SharePoint environment has server-side code blocks disabled?

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to add AllowServerSideScript to my web.config for this website.    Once I did that I got an odd error (CS1056) about it not expecting to find the '$'.   of course if I remove the symbol the page renders but the alt tag removed.

Comment: actually, that is a typo, you shouldn't need the `$` for `SPContext`, just for `$SPUrl`, I have updated the text in my posted answer.

Comment: The problem is removing the `$` from `SPContext` gets `<img id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_subhead" src="/housing/SiteAssets/Subsite_banner.png">`     Notice both the AlternateText and Tooltip vanished from the final rendered code.   But putting the `$` Gets me the CS1056 error.

Comment: You may need to add a `Page.DataBind();` to make sure your values get bound to those properties, I added an example to the posted answer.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for everything